# Org Capture - prepend after org header/config block?

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

One of my org capture templates (in my init.el) looks like the following:

```
("n" "Note" plain
           (file "/path/to/file.org")
           "* %^{Title} %U \n%? \n"
           :prepend t)
```

I'd like to see the following after I capture a note using this template:

```
#+TITLE: Notes
#+DESCRIPTION: a file of notes


* captured note [2019-10-14 Mon 18:06] 
* test note 2 [2019-10-14 Mon 13:00]
* test note 1 [2019-10-14 Mon 10:37]...
```

But what I actually get is:

```
* captured note [2019-10-14 Mon 18:06] 

#+TITLE: Notes
#+DESCRIPTION: a file of notes


* test note 2 [2019-10-14 Mon 13:00]
* test note 1 [2019-10-14 Mon 10:37]...
```

The "prepend" property almost does what I want - it prepends the headline to the beginning of the file, rather than the end. However, I'd like the header to stay at the top of the file.

Is there a way to prepend new headlines after the initial "#+" lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `plain` to `entry`.

See org manual [template elements](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Template-elements.html):

```
type
     The type of entry, a symbol.  Valid values are:

     ‘entry’
          An Org mode node, with a headline.  Will be filed as the child
          of the target entry or as a top-level entry.  The target file
          should be an Org file.

     ...

     ‘plain’
          Text to be inserted as it is.
```